# ¿Dónde se deben colocar los recursos en un proyecto JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Estoy realizando una aplicación web con JSP. Soy un poco nuevo. la aplicación trabaja con archivos de Word, Excel, etc.

Mi pregunta es, ¿Donde debo colocar estos archivos?  Por ejemplo, en C#, sé que se deben colocar en la carpeta bin/debug, pero en JSP no sé en qué carpeta será lo más factible.

A veces me sucede que el archivo se sube correctamente al sistema, pero tarda en reconocerlo. Por ahora coloco los archivos  en el directorio raíz del proyecto, es decir al mismo nivel de src, web y demás.  De antemano gracias.

Comment: Que usas para build? Maven? Ant? Usas eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo general, un proyecto Java EE suele tener un directorio llamado **resources** dentro de tu context path. Aquí van los estilos, scripts, fuentes, imágenes y lo que necesite la aplicación. Es como una convención. En JSF por ejemplo, es **obligatorio** hacerlo así.